# Prevent refresh button or prompt message if click refresh (flutter web)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

i know that for back button we can do by using the `willpopscope`,
but right now i' m trying to prevent user from refreshing the page, is there a way to disable the refresh button or prompt a message if user click the refresh button?

example of willpopscope

```
return WillPopScope (
onWillPop: () async {
  return shouldPop;
},
child: const Text('WillPopScope sample'),
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to `lib/web/index.html` will display a confirmation dialog:

```
...
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return "Changes that you made may not be saved.";
  }
</script>
...
</body>
...
```

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Could we may be reload that specific page in which we are in

Comment: @PrudhvikChirunomula yes there is a solution, I added it

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution for web would be:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
    html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async {
      if (event is html.BeforeUnloadEvent) event.returnValue = "Don't go!";
    });
```

Like this only the page where you want to warn, triggers the event. Otherwise all windows would trigger the event.